# SVN command for listing files to be merged without a working copy?

Tags: svn

I wonder if there is an SVN command to list what files are still to be merged from trunk to a feature branch, without needing a working copy? I.e. without checking out anything, but only by providing the urls for trunk and the branch.

I have a feature branch, sparse checked out (!) in a working copy. Since it is sparse checked out I can pick the files I need to work with, without having to have the whole (big) project checked out. While I am working with the files I keep them in sync with trunk by merging from trunk regularly. I now wonder if there is a way to list what other files on trunk, or new updates to the files I have already merged before, are left to be merged to have the branch totally in sync with trunk. Note, I only want to see the list of files, not merging them.

I tried the "svn merge  --dry-run" command and it seems to do what I want when I have a working copy that is NOT sparse checked out. It would be nice if I could provide the trunk url and the branch url and get that list of files without needing to have a working copy checked out, but it does not seem to be supported in the svn merge command. So, is there another way/command?

Comment: I also tried "svn diff --old=<trunk> --new=<branch> --summarize" which gave me a list of what have been changed on trunk but not whether things were already merged to the branch or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`svn mergeinfo`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) with 2 URLs, you'll get a list of revisions to be merged.

> List the operative revisions eligible to be merged from one branch to
>   another:

```
$ svn mergeinfo URL-OF-TRUNK URL-OF-BRANCH --show-revs eligible
r28
r30
```

After it for each revision from the above list with `svn log -<REVISION> URL-OF-BRANCH` you'll get list of files, maybe (out of ideas) have to be post-processed with `|sort -u`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that only seems to list revision numbers, not a "list of things still to be merged".

Comment: I have now been testing things a little bit more with "svn mergeinfo" and I thought it looked promising, when I provided the args "--log -v". Then I also got the info about the files involved and what operation has been performed (added, deleted, modified). However, now I also want to be able to do subtree merging of some of the files listed by "svn mergeinfo". The problem is that after doing so, the next time I run "svn mergeinfo" on the branch root I expect to see the files still remaining to be merged, but now the list is empty even though I only committed some of them.

Comment: ...that is if I run "svn mergeinfo" with the --recurse arg. If I run without it, the eligible list still contains the files that I have already merged.

Comment: I don't know if this is still an issue in the more recent version of SVN, but this could explain the issue I have:
https://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2009-08/0291.shtml